# ARM assembly - bl is branching to wrong address

Tags: c, assembly, arm, elf

### SOLVED: a power-cycle fixed it. Must have been electrical issue with the upper flash block that caused the HW execution unit to read wrong value from flash

I am assembly-stepping and something weird is happening.

I have two separate flash blocks and they both contain code.
Because they are so far apart, function calls from one block to the other requires an intermediate jump aka `veneer` which is automatically generated by the linker.

This has worked up until now and I did something - no idea what - to break it.

`0x1001a9ca: 0x0cf0c5fe   bl 0x10027758 <__atiupy_PutOutput2_veneer>`

After that is executed, the PC is `0x100275ce` **which is wrong**.

If I scroll in the disassembly window to `0x10027758`, I see the label `__atiupy_PutOutput2_veneer`.

Why is it jumping to wrong address?

**UPDATE**

It's jumping **from** C-code **to** C++ code. Yes I have `extern "C"` in the `.h` for the functions in C++ code called from C code.

C compile options are: `-x c -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -nostdlib -mthumb  -mtune=cortex-m4 -mlittle-endian  -Wdouble-promotion -DNDEBUG -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -c -save-temps=obj -g3 -gdwarf-2`

C++ compile options are: `-mthumb -mlittle-endian -x c++ -gdwarf-2 -g3 -fomit-frame-pointer -fnothrow-opt -ffreestanding   -fverbose-asm   -std=c++11 -c -fno-rtti -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions`

By request, some disassembly using `objdump -d`.

Where it's about to jump to `0x10027758` (but never gets there)

```
1001a9bc <mp_hal_stdout_tx_strn_cooked>:
1001a9bc:   b580        push    {r7, lr}
1001a9be:   b082        sub sp, #8
1001a9c0:   af00        add r7, sp, #0
1001a9c2:   6078        str r0, [r7, #4]
1001a9c4:   6039        str r1, [r7, #0]
1001a9c6:   6878        ldr r0, [r7, #4]
1001a9c8:   6839        ldr r1, [r7, #0]
1001a9ca:   f00c fec5   bl  10027758 <__atiupy_PutOutput2_veneer>
1001a9ce:   f107 0708   add.w   r7, r7, #8
1001a9d2:   46bd        mov sp, r7
1001a9d4:   bd80        pop {r7, pc}
1001a9d6:   bf00        nop
```

Where it should jump to

```
10027758 <__atiupy_PutOutput2_veneer>:
10027758:   b401        push    {r0}
1002775a:   4802        ldr r0, [pc, #8]    ; (10027764 <__atiupy_PutOutput2_veneer+0xc>)
1002775c:   4684        mov ip, r0
1002775e:   bc01        pop {r0}
10027760:   4760        bx  ip
10027762:   bf00        nop
10027764:   00035abd    .word   0x00035abd
```

It actually jumps to `0x100275ce` but I'm pasting the entire function located here

```
100275c8 <___ZN21CKinetisI2CController7DisableEv_veneer>:
100275c8:   b401        push    {r0}
100275ca:   4802        ldr r0, [pc, #8]    ; (100275d4 <___ZN21CKinetisI2CController7DisableEv_veneer+0xc>)
100275cc:   4684        mov ip, r0
100275ce:   bc01        pop {r0}
100275d0:   4760        bx  ip
100275d2:   bf00        nop
100275d4:   00029b2d    .word   0x00029b2d
```

I set a breakpoint at `mp_hal_stdout_tx_strn_cooked` and then assembly-stepped using `stepi`

```
p/x $pc
$2 = 0x1001a9c6
disass
Dump of assembler code for function mp_hal_stdout_tx_strn_cooked:
   0x1001a9bc <+0>: push    {r7, lr}
   0x1001a9be <+2>: sub sp, #8
   0x1001a9c0 <+4>: add r7, sp, #0
   0x1001a9c2 <+6>: str r0, [r7, #4]
   0x1001a9c4 <+8>: str r1, [r7, #0]
=> 0x1001a9c6 <+10>:    ldr r0, [r7, #4]
   0x1001a9c8 <+12>:    ldr r1, [r7, #0]
   0x1001a9ca <+14>:    bl  0x10027758 <__atiupy_PutOutput2_veneer>
   0x1001a9ce <+18>:    add.w   r7, r7, #8
   0x1001a9d2 <+22>:    mov sp, r7
   0x1001a9d4 <+24>:    pop {r7, pc}
End of assembler dump.
stepi
stepi
0x1001a9c8  23      atiupy_PutOutput2(str, len);
disass
Dump of assembler code for function mp_hal_stdout_tx_strn_cooked:
   0x1001a9bc <+0>: push    {r7, lr}
   0x1001a9be <+2>: sub sp, #8
   0x1001a9c0 <+4>: add r7, sp, #0
   0x1001a9c2 <+6>: str r0, [r7, #4]
   0x1001a9c4 <+8>: str r1, [r7, #0]
   0x1001a9c6 <+10>:    ldr r0, [r7, #4]
=> 0x1001a9c8 <+12>:    ldr r1, [r7, #0]
   0x1001a9ca <+14>:    bl  0x10027758 <__atiupy_PutOutput2_veneer>
   0x1001a9ce <+18>:    add.w   r7, r7, #8
   0x1001a9d2 <+22>:    mov sp, r7
   0x1001a9d4 <+24>:    pop {r7, pc}
End of assembler dump.
stepi
stepi
0x1001a9ca  23      atiupy_PutOutput2(str, len);
diasass
Undefined command: "diasass".  Try "help".
disass
Dump of assembler code for function mp_hal_stdout_tx_strn_cooked:
   0x1001a9bc <+0>: push    {r7, lr}
   0x1001a9be <+2>: sub sp, #8
   0x1001a9c0 <+4>: add r7, sp, #0
   0x1001a9c2 <+6>: str r0, [r7, #4]
   0x1001a9c4 <+8>: str r1, [r7, #0]
   0x1001a9c6 <+10>:    ldr r0, [r7, #4]
   0x1001a9c8 <+12>:    ldr r1, [r7, #0]
=> 0x1001a9ca <+14>:    bl  0x10027758 <__atiupy_PutOutput2_veneer>
   0x1001a9ce <+18>:    add.w   r7, r7, #8
   0x1001a9d2 <+22>:    mov sp, r7
   0x1001a9d4 <+24>:    pop {r7, pc}
End of assembler dump.
stepi
stepi
0x100275ce in ___ZN21CKinetisI2CController7DisableEv_veneer ()
disass
Dump of assembler code for function ___ZN21CKinetisI2CController7DisableEv_veneer:
   0x100275c8 <+0>: push    {r0}
   0x100275ca <+2>: ldr r0, [pc, #8]    ; (0x100275d4 <___ZN21CKinetisI2CController7DisableEv_veneer+12>)
   0x100275cc <+4>: mov r12, r0
=> 0x100275ce <+6>: pop {r0}
   0x100275d0 <+8>: bx  r12
   0x100275d2 <+10>:    nop
   0x100275d4 <+12>:    ldr r3, [sp, #180]  ; 0xb4
   0x100275d6 <+14>:    movs    r2, r0
End of assembler dump.
stepi
stepi
0x100275d0 in ___ZN21CKinetisI2CController7DisableEv_veneer ()
disass
Dump of assembler code for function ___ZN21CKinetisI2CController7DisableEv_veneer:
   0x100275c8 <+0>: push    {r0}
   0x100275ca <+2>: ldr r0, [pc, #8]    ; (0x100275d4 <___ZN21CKinetisI2CController7DisableEv_veneer+12>)
   0x100275cc <+4>: mov r12, r0
   0x100275ce <+6>: pop {r0}
=> 0x100275d0 <+8>: bx  r12
   0x100275d2 <+10>:    nop
   0x100275d4 <+12>:    ldr r3, [sp, #180]  ; 0xb4
   0x100275d6 <+14>:    movs    r2, r0
End of assembler dump.
```

**Assembly file before compilation**

Someone wanted the assembly file output from the compiler, rather than `objdump`'s interpretation. This output is a result of the compile option `-save-temps=obj`

```
.LFE14:
    .size   mp_hal_stdout_tx_strn, .-mp_hal_stdout_tx_strn
    .section    .text.mp_hal_stdout_tx_strn_cooked,"ax",%progbits
    .align  2
    .global mp_hal_stdout_tx_strn_cooked
    .thumb
    .thumb_func
    .type   mp_hal_stdout_tx_strn_cooked, %function
mp_hal_stdout_tx_strn_cooked:
.LFB15:
    .loc 1 22 0
    .cfi_startproc
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 8
    @ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    push    {r7, lr}
.LCFI11:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 7, -8
    .cfi_offset 14, -4
    sub sp, sp, #8
.LCFI12:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    add r7, sp, #0
.LCFI13:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 7
    str r0, [r7, #4]
    str r1, [r7, #0]
    .loc 1 23 0
    ldr r0, [r7, #4]
    ldr r1, [r7, #0]
    bl  atiupy_PutOutput2
    .loc 1 25 0
    add r7, r7, #8
    mov sp, r7
    pop {r7, pc}
    .cfi_endproc
```

**(Sad) update**

I created the minimal example but the issue doesn't occur. Therefore, I think it's something in my environment. I will start reverting local changes and will update. I wouldn't call the below code *complete* because you'd need the linker file but since it doesn't reproduce the issue, I don't see a point in providing everything.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "common.h"

int main()
{
    test1();
}

int main_test()
{
    int a = 5;
    a = 23424 * a;
    return a;
}
```

**test.c**

```
#include "common.h"

void test1()
{
    int a;
    a = main_test();
    a *= 2;
}
```

**common.h**

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif //#ifdef __cplusplus


int main_test();
void test1();


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif //#ifdef __cplusplus
```

**main.obj** is placed in "lower" flash block while **test.obj** is in upper block. When jumping from upper to lower, the PC **correctly** jumps to the right address for `veneer`.

Comment: @Adrian: yes, I got your notification in chat, and was able to follow a link back to the question.  BTW, terminology problem: *Assembly file before compilation* doesn't make sense.  asm is the *result* of compilation.  An object file is the result of assembling the compiler output.  (Many compilers have an assembler built-in and emitting asm instead of machine code is just an option, but gcc doesn't.)

Comment: @PeterCordes solved it: power-cycle fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: a power-cycle fixed it. Must have been electrical issue with the upper flash block that caused the HW execution unit to read wrong value from flash.